# How do I connect an LCD Monitor with a DVI-D port to a CPU with a VGA port only?

Tags: dvi, vga, adapter

So I'm returning this DVI-I to VGA adapter which I bought by mistake (and by mistake I mean not researching about how many types of DVI connection there are). Is there a way to still use a DVI connection to my CPU?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way is to buy a converter. There are DVI-D/VGA converters [on the market](http://www.amazon.co.uk/DVI-D-Adapter-Convertor-HDTV-Electronics/dp/B003K3060I) - just double check before you buy (or buy locally so it's easier to return/swap).

This wouldn't give you a digital output - your graphics card is strictly analogue - but will get you a picture on your monitor.

Comment: So I'll just buy another adapter, just this time it's a DVI-D to VGA type, right? I read somewhere a DVI-D connection will not work on an analog system unless I use an electronic converter, like this

http://www.datapro.net/products/usb-to-dvi-video-adapter.html

I came here to find out if that's true or if a standard DVI-D to VGA adapter will do. Thanks again.

Comment: @d4ryl3 - Ah, that does ring faint bells now. You might be right there, not sure though.

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate the help, though. :)

Answer (score 3):

If the monitor has a VGA port, use that!

You gain nothing by using an external converter, and potentially lose out compared to the converter built into the monitor.  You're not going to get digital straight through, so reduce the links in the signal chain.

External converters should only be used when there is no other possible signal path.  You have a signal path already, and it's generally better than what you can get in an external package.

Comment: Yes, thank you. That was also my question, if I should even try a DVI connection. I'll stick to VGA for now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If the monitor really has no analogue inputs, then a video card with a DVI output is your only solution.

Comment: Well, it has a VGA port. I'm just trying to see if I could get a DVI connection from it, too. Or would the display be just the same?